# I've successfully added gzip compression in .htaccess of magento yet its not running

Tags: .htaccess, magento, compression, gzip

This is the code of my.htaccess for the gzip compression. I've inserted this code in my htaccess yet its showing 0% gzip compression on gtmetrix. WHy?

```
    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
```

also I have this code too after it for further...

```
    <IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 18000
   php_value max_input_time 18000
   php_value max_input_vars 18000
   php_value memory_limit -1
   php_value post_max_size 20000M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200000M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 18000
   php_value max_input_time 18000
   php_value max_input_vars 18000
   php_value memory_limit -1
   php_value post_max_size 20000M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 200000M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following line is present (and not commented out) in your apache configuration (httpd.conf):

`LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so`

You can also try to enable deflate using the following command:

`a2enmod deflate`

`service apache2 restart`

Try to test your URL again, using this tool:
https://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

Comment: I've tested using the above mentioned url, and its showing green signal that my website is compressed. What else to make gtmetrix 100% on gzip compression???

Comment: Take a look under gtmetrix what issues they are complaining. Sometimes you are loading external resources, out of your hands. Let me know your public URL and I could review and share my advices. I'm not convinced if it is possible to achieve the best results without complete refactor the code sometimes. Try to get a popular website in your country and test it against these tools. You'll notice that all of them (except facebook and google), will NOT achieve A grade. I couldn't agree with this speed battle. This is my point of view.